# LocalIndex files are not copied during deployment process

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sensenet

I am working on an asp.net project which uses Sense/Net packages and I am having an issue with getting the LocalIndex files to copy when I publish the application. The publish method is via Web Deploy Package and the package location is a zip file on the drive. Upon publication, the published application does not include the App_Data folder, and therefore does not contain the LocalIndex files, so the SenseNet Content Repository is missing content.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to publish index files along source code this way (and yes, Visual Studio skips the App_Data folder). The index is an essential part of a system and *it should be in sync with the database*. So if you have a production db, you should have an index in the production web folder and it *should not be modified by subsequent publish operations* (for example if somebody created or modified a content in the live environment, the newly published index would ruin those changes).

If this is an *initial publish*, you may copy a local index manually or execute a re-index operation on the server (using the SnAdmin tool) after publish to create a fresh index. Or (but I'm not sure this workaround is acceptable) you may even copy the index folder inside the generated web deploy zip package, if you want to deploy this package to many servers.

Comment: If it's not best practice to re-index the content repository, what is the recommended way to refresh the index in the event it becomes corrupt or simply needs to be rebuilt. Also, it is our intent to store content externally of the database using Sense/Net Blob storage management. And if versioning is used, typical of document management, rebuilding the index should not impact content or metadata in a database, because it is versioned, or isn't that the case?

Comment: Rebuilding the index should be a very rare operation, as you say, for example when it gets corrupted. If you think that the index of certain documents got corrupted, you can reindex a subtree (e.g. a folder in the repository), not the whole database (see the index snadmin tool: https://community.sensenet.com/docs/snadmin-tools/).

Comment: But usually you do not have to do that. Just make sure you copy/move the index along with the database - for example when you create a db backup, you should backup the web folder (or at least the index) too.

Comment: And yes, indexing does not impact documents (versions) in the db, the index can be thought of as a "view" of the db that can be recreated based on the db.